# when i echo input and submit button resizes

Tags: php, html, css

So i have a weird problem, the problem is when i echo something out in php code, for example an error, the input box and submit button size goes off i mean inputtext place gets smaller and submit button gets bigger,

before:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ6OF.jpg

code:

```
if($row) // Ime nije registrovano kod dole
{
    echo '

        <div class="transbox" position = "center">

        <center><p>Ime koje ste uneli je vec registrovano.</p>
        <p>Molimo vas da odaberete drugo ime koje cete koristiti na serveru.</p></center>

        </div>
    ';            
}
```

// css

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"]
{
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type="submit"]
{
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #eee;
    background: #0098cb;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover
{   
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    color: #eee;
    background: #00b8cb;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: you need to show how/where you echo that html...

Comment: here for example http://pastebin.com/XFDSYReM

Comment: that doesn't help. we don't go "outside" to look at code, and what you did post is useless. WHERE is that echoed html going? you need to show how what it gets inserted INTO.

Comment: You probably have a script/library that wraps your dumps in `<pre>`. And for some reason, it doesn't close them. I'm just speculating, but it looks like it. Inspect your `html` output (view source) and you'll find your answer.

Comment: I'm disturbed by the text's contrast in the image :(